# Grizzly 5hp planer trips breaker on my generator at start up

Tags: generator

Trying to run my shop off grid.  I have the duromax 12000 watt generator. It has a 50 watt connection but a 30 watt breaker. The generator is wired to a panel in the shop.  The generator seems to run most everything with no problem.  The 240 outlet I’m trying to use is about 5 ft from the box and on a 50 amp breaker.  I have a Grizzly 20” planer, 5hp motor, 23 amp.  At startup, (nothing else in the shop running). The generator Boggs down a bit and trips the breaker on the generator.  The panel breaker doesn’t trip.  I’m assuming the start up amps on the planer are too high.  My question is, can the generator be used, or do I need to replace it?  If I have to replace it, what size generator do I need?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you mean your generator has a 50 **amp** connection and 30 **amp** breaker, instead of watt? Secondly, when you state nothing else in the shop is running, does that include lights and heating/cooling are also all off?

Comment: That planer would probably push that generator when running.  Startup amps are probably too much, but one thing to try is to use larger wire from the generator to the panel.  I had similar problem with a 1/2hp well pump motor.  I had to use 10 gauge at the shortest distance to power the pump, instead of the normal 14 gauge.  This was with a 5000 watt gen.

Comment: Yes, I’m sorry. Amps not watts.  Everything is off.  Just trying to run the planer.

Comment: I used heavy wire.  I don’t remember what gauge, I know it’s bigger than 10 though

Comment: You probably have enough wattage in the generator, but that 30 amp breaker is just big enough for the running amps of the planner.  Probably need a 50 amp breaker for the start amps.

Comment: You need a different planer or a *much larger* generator.

Comment: I can’t replace the planer.  You say a much bigger generator, but would the size of the generator matter, if it has the same breaker?  Is 50 amps big enough?

Comment: Motors can use a huge amount of current on startup. Thus, it's difficult to say exactly how large a generator you'll need for this particular motor unless you either try it out with a partciular generator your are planning to purchase, or measure the actual startup surge when starting it from a grid-type supply. The grid supply can exploit the grid's huge capacity and breaker trip curves to deal with startup surges  3 or more times the nameplate rating of the breaker. A generator has to be able to supply all that power itself.

Comment: After doing a bit of research, I’m beginning to see how difficult it is to match the right size generator to a particular motor.  It appears too large of generator can be as problematic as too small over time.  It’s way over my head, but I appreciate the help from everyone

Comment: Off hand might need a 15000w gen for the start up amps.  But will also need a 50 or 60 amp breaker on it..  It will also depend on the generator.  I had problems with a 5000w gen powering my well pump.  Before I got that gen, we had a very small honda gen I think only put out 13 amps, it had no problem powering the well pump with a long(25/50ft) small gauge extension cable.

Comment: One thing to try is adding a soft starter (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor_soft_starter) to the planer. I’m putting this as a comment because I have no direct experience with doing this and don’t know for sure that it would be sufficient for your generator.

Comment: 30A x 240V = 7.2kw, so "12KW" is *complete marketing hogwash,* by the way. Despite the current higher price of diesel, if getting a bigger generator, consider diesel, since fuel consumption scales much more "as loaded" on diesel (so half load ~ 1/2 fuel consumption) where gasoline/propane will use much more than half the fuel at half the load. And if the higher price of diesel causes you to get into making your own biodiesel from used fry oil, the price goes down again...

Comment: I’m looking at a soft starter now.  I’ll try to get back and let you know how it works

Comment: @Ecnerwal  I think it might also be to the type of breakers used on the generator.  Maybe they use a rapid trip type.  I had two gens to run a well pump.  The small tiny one no problem, the big gen(almost 4 times the size in watts) would trip the breaker every time.